# How to return more specific double value in Java

Tags: java, double

While studying programming in Java lately, I found out that the double type can only return up to limited decimal places (of course I could code to return more, e.g. by typing %.20f, but it would just return 0 behind the certain decimal places). Is there no way to return more specific numbers in more decimal places?

Here is an example code.

```
public class DoubleCalculation {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 1000;
        double b = 2.54643;
        System.out.printf("%.20f\n", a/b);
    }
}
```

and it would return 392.70665205797920000000.

Comment: you can try to use `BigDecimal` class... for operating exactly

Comment: IEEE floating point numbers can only have 16 digits of precision.  Can't do better than that.

Comment: Use DecimalFormat instead ;)

Comment: @duffymo: 52 *bits* of precision. That often doesn't neatly map to a number of decimal digits. (Example, 0.1d).

Comment: First of all, your method doesn’t *return* anything. You are just printing a value. Second, the number of nonzero decimal places doesn’t say anything about the *precision*. In your example, the input value `2.54643` has only six decimal digits and printing more than that for the result is just faking a precision which is not there. I could replace the zeros at the result’s end with just random numbers and you wouldn’t notice…

Comment: 16 digits is correct: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the commentors already mentioned you can use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). See below for a small code sample:

```
    int a = 1000;
    double b = 2.54643;
    System.out.printf("%.20f\n", a/b);

    BigDecimal a_2 = new BigDecimal(a);
    BigDecimal b_2 = new BigDecimal("2.54643");
    BigDecimal result = a_2.divide(b_2, 20, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BigDecimal which allows you to specify a precision (the 50 in the divide() below):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1000");
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("2.54643");
    System.out.println(a.divide(b, 50, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN).toString());
}
```

Prints: 392.70665205797921010984005058061678506772226214739851